# Retrieve Entity Id from REST API using Order ID

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.9, rest-api

Working with the REST API on Magento 2.1.9 I notice that the Entity ID is needed for the `/V1/orders/` endpoints. How can `entity_id` be retrieved via the API when I only know `increment_id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][field]=increment_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][value]=**INCREMENT_ID_HERE**&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

It should return the order details with the matching increment_id. From this you can get the order_id.

If you wanted to only return the order-Id in the request -

```
rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][field]=increment_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][value]=**INCREMENT_ID_HERE**&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&fields=items[items[order_id]]
```

EDIT: Realised it was actualy the **entity_id** you wanted from this, so it would be -

rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][field]=increment_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][value]=**INCREMENT_ID_HERE**&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&fields=items[entity_id]

Comment: Thanks - although I found the solution a while ago, should have checked back on SE immediately!

Comment: @all, I can't get order increment_id by this code. Can you post/comment your full code? It will be great help for others.